# Switching to Chrome in 11.10?

Tags: chromium, 11.10

I just read an article that said Ubuntu is switching to Chrome for 11.10. Is this true and if so, is it going to be Chrome or Chromium???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firefox will still be the default Web Browser in 11.10.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/firefox-to-remain-the-default-browser-in-ubuntu-11-10-uds/) While it was proposed that Chrome or Chromium would replace it, the end decision was that Firefox would remain as default in 11.10 when it was discussed (or rather set to discuss, but then the discussion was canceled, automatically keeping things the same) at the Ubuntu Developer Summit.

Also it was set to be Chromium since it is fully open source and Google Chrome has some proprietary code in it.

Comment: The article you quoted was from May 9th the article I read was from the 18th http://goo.gl/iNMq1 I read the same articles, the one I quoted kinda surprised me!?

Comment: Hmm. That is a bit strange. A quick browse through several of the news sites I browse shows that they are all claiming Firefox is still the default. One site said the debate was still up in the air, but the only site I've seen that claims that Chrome is going to be included is the one you linked. I would assume that they made a mistake until we see more with the Alpha in June.

Comment: Also one of those sources that states no change in the default browser is Andrew from webupd8.org who I know personally attended UDS. Again, we'll see if Canonical is just being secretive or not in a bit.

Comment: Ubuntu's Love for Firefox will not go "so easily", Google chrome can never be default browser of Ubuntu. Chromium can be but Firefox has changed their updation policy and we may see versions upto Firefox 7 by the end of this year. I don't see a need of change of default browser in ubuntu. Moreover firefox looks more compatible with unity's themes. 
Any ways I have an article good to read about coverting your ubuntu into chrome os 
http://tutafuta.com/2011/05/13/convert-your-ubuntu-into-chrome-os/

Comment: What I don't like about chrome is that there is no way to not save history like in Firefox. Incognito mode doesn't really work for me. If you know of a way let me know.

Comment: The Chrome/Chromium "web app store" has a bunch of extensions for keeping yourself from being tracked here is the link http://goo.gl/romop  (you have to be on Chrome/Chromium to access this link) Also if you go into Preferences>Under the Hood>Content Settings>Cookies, you can set Chromium to whatever content settings you want.